# A much better way to automatically log user in after account verification in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm working on a practice project with spring boot and thymeleaf.

I have a registration form. After the user has registered their account, a verification code will be sent to their email. The next page is where they will enter the code.

I'm using RedirectAttributes to store the verification code id so I will be able to lookup/confirm the code in the verification code page. I am also using RedirectAttributes to pass the user email and raw password to the verification code page so they can be automatically logged in after confirming their account.

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String processRegisterForm(@ModelAttribute NewAccountRequest newAccountRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Long verifyCodeId = accountService.createAccount(newAccountRequest);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("verifyCodeId", verifyCodeId);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userEmail", newAccountRequest.getEmail());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("rawPassword", newAccountRequest.getPassword());
    return "redirect:/register/verify-account"; 
}
```

Now, here is where it gets messy. In the GetMapping for the page to enter verification code, I also had to add the exact same attribute I added in the above PostMapping. Like this:

```
@GetMapping("/register/verify-account")
public String loadVerificationPage(@ModelAttribute("verifyCodeId") String verifyCodeId, @ModelAttribute("userEmail") String userEmail, @ModelAttribute("rawPassword") String rawPassword, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("verifyCodeId", verifyCodeId);
    model.addAttribute("userEmail", userEmail);
    model.addAttribute("rawPassword", rawPassword);
    return "verify-account";
}
```

And in thymeleaf, I did this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="verificationCodeId" th:value="${verifyCodeId}">
<input type="hidden" name="userEmail", th:value="${userEmail}">
<input type="hidden" name="rawPassword" th:value="${rawPassword}">
```

And in the PostMapping for the page to enter verification code:

```
@PostMapping("/register/verify-account")
public String confirmVerifyCode(@RequestParam String enteredVerificationCode, @RequestParam String verificationCodeId, @RequestParam String userEmail, @RequestParam String rawPassword,
                                HttpServletRequest request) {
    accountService.confirmVerificationCode(enteredVerificationCode, verificationCodeId);
    try {
        request.login(userEmail, rawPassword);
    }
    catch (ServletException e) {
        System.out.println("Login error: " + e);
    }
    return "redirect:/?loginSuccess";
}
```

I can't get the flash attribute directly in the PostMapping of register/verify-account so I needed to use input fields in thymeleaf

**I feel like there's a much easier and simpler way to do this because this just seem really messy. Any tips? Please also note that I haven't added any validations so ignore that. And could their be any security risks in using flash attributes to hold verification codes and passwords? Or to storing verification code in "hidden" input fields?**

The registration flow:

1. User loads the register page
2. When the form is submitted, processRegisterForm() is called;
3. The user's account is created and the verification code id is returned.
4. To confirm the verification code in the next page, the id is stored in a flash attribute. The user's email and raw password is also stored. User is redirected to the page to enter verification code
5. For the GetMapping of the page to enter verification code, model attributes are added to store the code id, user email, and password. In thymeleaf, hidden input fields are used to hold those 3 values mentioned.
6. The PostMapping of the page to enter verification code gets those 3 fields and uses it to verify/auto login the user.

I'm hopping there is a much better way to achieve this. Sorry for the long post. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up cleaning the code up by using a DTO instead of those request params. Don't know why I didn't do that earlier.

In the /register/verify-account mapping, before logging in the user, I did this:

```
if (passwordEncoder.matches(userPassword, dbPassword)) {
        try {
            request.login(account.getEmail(), userPassword);
        }
        catch (ServletException e) {
            System.out.println("Login after account verification failed" + e);
        }
    }
else {
        System.out.println("fishy fishy");
}
```

I'm not sure if this really adds any security but it's good enough for me for now. Special thanks to these people for helping me: , , and

EDIT: I ended up using HttpSession